# Custom Hotkey/KeyMapping? in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

I dont have a numberpad on my laptop. In a game the numpad 4 is a hotkey for an item i like. How can i setup windows 7 to forward another key (such as o or fn+o) to numpad 4?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), depending on the game.  What game is it?

Comment: WC3: Frozen Throne

Comment: I couldnt figure this out. It seems like it doesnt recognize shift (i tried using shift o and then O:: with no luck). Then i tried ::df:: (as in press them at the same time to trigger) but it looks like it triggers when i write df then a non alphabet character after it. And shift, ctrl, etc which i can hit with my pinky quickly doesnt count.

How do i write a trigger i can hit quickly with my left hand? Currently my file is `::df::Send {Numpad4}`

Comment: @acidzombie24 In AutoHotkey, you use [special symbols](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for modifier keys: `^` for Ctrl, `+` for Shift, `!` for Alt, and `#` for the Windows key.